# Flutter - how to add a background text to StatefulWidget for random color generating

Tags: flutter, background-color

just start to study Flutter and I try to create a widget with random color generator, and partly i did it, by I don't know how to add background text to the center of screen. Maybe someone can help me, please?

```
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: MyPage()));
}

class MyPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyPageState createState() => new _MyPageState();
}

class _MyPageState extends State<MyPage> {
  Random random = new Random();

  Color color ;

  void changeRandomColor() {
    setState(() {
      color = Color.fromARGB(
        //or with fromRGBO with fourth arg as _random.nextDouble(),
        random.nextInt(256),
        random.nextInt(256),
        random.nextInt(256),
        random.nextInt(256),
      );
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body:
          InkWell(
            onTap: changeRandomColor,
            child: Container(
              color: color,
            ),
          )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Nothing need to do. I just checked with dartpad. Maybe you are seeing white for the first time. Just tap on the screen and let me know if thats not the case.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it right just give Container fullscreen width and height and you're good to go.

child property in Container can add text widget in the center, like

```
 Container( child: Center(child:Text('data')) );
```

Comment: Thanks but maybe you can tell, how to add a text widget to Container as a background in order to see it in a center of screen. Thank you in advance.

Comment: child property in Container can add text widget in center, like

Container(
  child: Center(child:Text('data'))
)